# pyTelegramBotAPI. How to save state in next_step_handler solution?

Tags: python, telegram, py-telegram-bot-api

User in my solution goes step by step by typing message in telegram. The problem is that after server reboot his state not saving and he needs to begin again.

For example, if user on 'process_mid' step, after rebooting, he can't go to 'process_end'. User can only begin new stage by typing 'start' command.

```
bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def process_start(message):
    text = 'start'
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, process_mid)


def process_mid(message):
    text = 'mid'
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, process_end)


def process_end(message):
    text = 'end'
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text)

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to store your user's state along with user's chat ID in database and verify state from there.

For it try to create something like

```
class States(enumerate):
    # Enter all states like numbers
    S_START = 0
    ...
```

Also, create function for getting state from db:

```
def get_current_state(user_id):
    # getting state by user's chat ID from DB
    ...
```

After, just write in DB for each user's chat id state (change it in every handler you need) and validate it in handler func:

```
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: get_current_state(message.chat.id) == config.States.S_START.value)
def some_function(message):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

From my experience with this bot, you need to save all data to a file (or database for that matter) if you want to pick up from where you left off.

You can save your progress along the way and in the `process_start` function identify the user with his `message.chat.id` at the entrance to the function  and if that value exists in the file (database) then register the next step accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This Example will show you how to use **register_next_step handler**
https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/step_example.py